# Magento query caching

Tags: php, caching, magento

How to cache the query result in magento if I am creating some module.

Basically I am creating one module for the announcement in which admin will add some announcement from the admin and it will be displayed on the front end(live website)

Now if the information entered though the admin is not dynamic so I want to cache the information while modifying(add, edit delete )  and show in front end. it will save my database query time

Comment: @richsage I have modified the question

Comment: I would like to mention that another option is to have the admin user edit a static block, and then have that static block displayed anywhere you want on the fronend. We have a "holiday notice" static block that we enable and disable and it displays on the homepage and a few other key pages like My Cart.  It is easier than writing a new module for it. But if your message is supposed to integrate with other functionality in your custom module, then my suggestion doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only cache the query result your block is still going to be generated every time. (Besides, MySQL already has a query cache)

It is better to cache the block output which saves even more effort for the server.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput